# AWS RDS SDK returning difference from AWS Console

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-sdk

I am using AWS Nodejs SDK to get RDS snapshots by

```
const snapshots = await rds.describeDBSnapshots().promise();
```

Its returning a different amount of snapshots from the AWS console with the same user. (Same access key / secret key)
In the UI i can view all the snapshots but the function from SDK is not returning the same amount

Answer (score 1):

Is it returning more or less? (my guess is less) - are you sure its not paginating the return values for you?

I believe this call defaults to returning a max of 100 records if you don't specify, and if you have more than 100 would need to page thru the results with subsequent calls

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions describing RDS snapshots, RDS instances and RDS clusters.

I was only using RDS instances to grab snapshots but the remaining were in the describe rds cluster snapshots function